# Android: How to get a list of all cache files in an app?

Tags: android, caching

Here are functions I use to save and load cache:

```
public static void SAVE_CACHE(Context context, String key, Object object) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(object);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
}

public static Object LOAD_CACHE(Context context, String key) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(key);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Object object = ois.readObject();
    return object;
}
```

Let's say I have 3 arraylists of object `Contact` saved in cache:

```
List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
contacts.add(new Contact());

SAVE_CACHE(context, "cache1", contacts);
SAVE_CACHE(context, "cache2", contacts);
SAVE_CACHE(context, "cache3", contacts);
```

Is it possible to get which cache keys contain an object? I'd like to have an arraylist of that cache1, cache2 and cache2.

Comment: do  you mean that you want to find a list all the cache files available?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you will need the pointer to the Directory that stores the files, you can get that from the context object using,

```
File dir = context.getFilesDir()
```

This returns a object of type [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles()). On this you can use the function `listFiles()` to get the list of cache files, like so:

```
 dir.listFiles()
```

Here's the documentation for [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) and [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) that have these functions for further reading.

Hope that helps..

Comment: anytime! glad it helped!

Comment: This return files in internal storage in files sub folder.
I think the question is for list of files in cache files in internal storage in cache sub folder.